# Python CExtension gives ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, distutils, python-c-api, cextension

I am using Python 3 with Anaconda Spyder on CentOS 7.  I am trying to get the Python CExtension working by following this video. 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a65JdvOaygM

I have all of my files in /home/peter/pythonCExtensions which is in the PYTHONPATH

I have a file myModule.c that has the following contents.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "/home/peter/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/Python.h"

int Cfib(int n)
{
    if (n<2){
        return n;
    } else {
        return Cfib(n-1)+Cfib(n-2);
    }
}

static PyObject* fib(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
int n;

if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &n))
    return NULL;

    return Py_BuildValue("i", Cfib(n));
}

static PyObject* version(PyObject* self){
    return Py_BuildValue("s", "Version 1.0");
}

static PyMethodDef myMethods[] = {
    {"fib", fib, METH_VARARGS, "Calculates the Fibronacci numbers"},
    {"version", (PyCFunction)version, METH_NOARGS, "Returns the version"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef myModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "myModule",
    "Fibronacci Module",
    -1,
    myMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_myModule(void){
    return PyModule_Create(&myModule);
}
```

I made another file, setup.py, that has the following contents.

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module = Extension("MyModule", sources = ["myModule.c"])

setup(name="PackageName",
        version="1.0",
        description="This is a package for myModule",
        ext_modules = [module])
```

I ran

```
python3 setup.py install
```

and got

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MyModule.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> /home/peter/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing /home/peter/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PackageName-1.0-py3.7.egg-info
```

I then copied MyModule.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  and myModule.o into /home/peter/pythonCExtensions.

I then opened Spyder and created a file, CInterface.py, that contains only

```
import myModule
```

However, when I run this file (F5) I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-c29fad851da0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/peter/Simple3dShapes/CInterface.py',     wdir='/home/peter/Simple3dShapes')

  File "/home/peter/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/peter/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/peter/Simple3dShapes/CInterface.py", line 19, in <module>
import myModule

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myModule'

sudo yum install tree
```

resulted in

Install  1 Package

```
Total download size: 46 k
Installed size: 87 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
tree-1.6.0-10.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                    |  46 kB  00:00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : tree-1.6.0-10.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                            1/1 
  Verifying  : tree-1.6.0-10.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                        1/1 

Installed:
  tree.x86_64 0:1.6.0-10.el7                                                                                                                                                                                       

Complete!
```

Comment: `static struct PyModuleDef myModule = {PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "MyModule", ...`, `PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_MyModule...`  (***M**yModule*)? **Or better**, the other way around: `module = Extension("myModule", sources = ["myModule.c"])...`

Comment: Can you do me a favour? `apt-get install tree` and run tree in your route directory. And paste that output. Just edit your post and show us your structure.

Comment: Thanks very much, @CristiFati.  That was indeed the problem.  Thanks very much.

Comment: @daunadeem.  I have added the results to my question.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: Building C and C++ Extensions](https://docs.python.org/extending/building.html#building-c-and-c-extensions).

At its core, this is a typo (upper *vs.* lower case), combined with the fact that on *Nix*, file names are case sensitive (most likely, it couldn't be reproduced on *Win*).

So, your module is called ***m**yModule* (function *PyInit_**m**yModule*), but it resides in a file called ***M**yModule.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so*, which is not *OK* because the 2 names must match. 
Correct that by specifying the proper extension name in *setup.py*:

```py
module = Extension("myModule", sources = ["myModule.c"])
```

As a side remark, don't name the module *myModule* (in general don't name stuff *myStuff* - personally, I truly hate it :) ), such a name states that the purpose is unclear. You could use *e.g.* *fibonacci_module* as a name.